# Double Slash behind URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, url-rewriting, apache2

I'm forwarding any non www and non SSL connection to https://www.* with this code in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.tld/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But when I try to put this exact code in my 000-default.conf and 000-default-le-ssl.conf, it puts a double slash (https://www.domain.tld**//**) behind the URL. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when I try to put this exact code in my 000-default.conf and 000-default-le-ssl.conf, it puts a double slash (`https://www.domain.tld//`) behind the URL. Why?

It is because in http server configs leading slash is also matches in `RewriteRule` unlike .htaccess files.

You can use this rule to make it behave same in both type of files:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://www.domain.tld/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

Or else:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.tld%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
```

Comment: Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: It worked! Thanks. Btw you can use http://www.redirect-checker.org/ for such things! :)

Comment: That site is only for checking redirects but you still need to get the rules right.